# group_concat does not show all the values mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
ModelName.all(:having=>"count(receipt_no)>1",:select=>"school_id,group_concat(id SEPARATOR ',') as f_ids,receipt_no,count(distinct id) as id_count,count(receipt_no) as  rec_count",:conditions=>"receipt_no is not null",:group=>"receipt_no")
```

Output is

```
 +------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| receipt_no | school_id | id_count | f_ids                                                                                                                                                                               | rec_count |
+------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 1261       | 1783      | 2        | 557660,557661                                                                                                                                                                       | 2         |
| 14/15-     | 1783      | 1209     | 68352,77056,113664,56320,68353,77057,113665,56321,68354,56322,68355,81923,173571,113667,56323,68356,94980,56324,68357,56325,68358,80390,56326,68359,80391,110599,56327,80392,885... | 1209      |
| 15-        | 1783      | 112      | 344067,344068,344069,344070,344075,326923,373261,373262,345882,360218,344091,361755,347685,341542,347689,360233,351530,358705,352829,324674,341576,324684,360018,368469,371541,3... | 112       |
```

Here `group_concat` does not show all the values but the count of items as same as the count receipt no. Suppose the items in the f_ids column is more  than 200 character then its not showing all the values . In other case it  will show correct value

Comment: `group_concat` of mysql has limitation for string length you can refer http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-trick-overcoming-group_concat-limitation-in-special-cases

Comment: It looks like the 200 character limit is being imposed by whatever software you're using to display the table. MySQL's default limit on `GROUP_CONCAT` is `1024` characters, and it doesn't put ellipsis at the end.

Comment: Is there any way to change that limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Run this code in MySQL console, then this code will change default group_concat character limit to 1000000 characters.

If you want to use in rails console,you can use in this following way

```
sql = "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Please note:
This configuration will work only in that session